# GetSchemaTable returns weird/incorrect columnames

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I have MS-SQL Database and want to read the data of a table in a DataTable.
When I use GetSchemaTable to load in DataTable, I can't get de correct column names.
The code to get the schema:

```
SqlCommand nCmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM import", con);
SqlDataReader reader = nCmd.ExecuteReader();

DataTable schemaTable = reader.GetSchemaTable();

while (reader.Read())
{
   returnData += reader["NAME"];
}

reader.Close();
```

The reader["NAME"] is filled with expected data. (Just to be sure I can get it by it's columname.)

I try to read the columnnames from schema:

```
DataColumnCollection columns = schemaTable.Columns;

foreach (DataColumn column in columns)
{
    returnData += column.ColumnName;
}
```

It returns:

```
ColumnOrdinal
ColumnSize
NumericPrecision
NumericScale
IsUnique
IsKey
BaseServerName
BaseCatalogName
...etc instead of the read column names.
```

I seached for it. And there seems to be a bug about it. I was directed to use OleDbConnection, but it makes no difference in this case.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should walk over the rows of the `schemaTable`. Now you're querying the definition of the metatable.

Comment: To expand on what @Caramiriel says: in the schemaTable there are columns each of which contains data about the columns in the schemaTable. The rows of the schemaTable each contains data about a column of the DataTable the schemaTable is connected with. So you need to go through each row of the schemaTable to get the data about each column of the DataTable.